# Integral of product of three spherical harmonics with derivatives

Tags: special-functions, mathematical-physics, spherical-harmonics

In a [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/integral-of-the-product-of-three-spherical-harmonics?noredirect=1&lq=1), the integral of products of three spherical harmonics was discussed:

\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi Y_{l_1}^{m_1}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l_2}^{m_2}(\theta,\phi)&Y_{l_3}^{m_3}(\theta,\phi)\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi
=\\
&\sqrt{\frac{(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)(2l_3+1)}{4\pi}} \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l_3  \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \\ \end{array} } \right) \left( {\begin{array}{ccc} l_1 & l_2 & l_3  \\ m_1 & m_2 & m_3  \\ \end{array} } \right)
\end{align}

Is there such a formula when we add tangential gradients, like

$$\int_{\Bbb{S}^2} Y_{l_1}^{m_1} Y_{l_2}^{m_2} \nabla Y_{l_3}^{m_3} \text{ or }\int_{\Bbb{S}^2} Y_{l_1}^{m_1}\nabla Y_{l_2}^{m_2} \nabla Y_{l_3}^{m_3}
$$

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: My idea was that physicists are maybe more familiar with particular properties of spherical harmonics than mathematicians... In particular, the question regarding the integral of the product of three harmonic functions received more detailed answers on the physics site than on mathematics...

Comment: To be fair, I'd also have argued the linked previous question should have been asked on the math site as well, but it is not possible to migrate such an old question.

Comment: From representation theory, there should indeed be an explicit expression, but it might be a little work to obtain it, but/and I myself would not be able to do so immediately...